# how to update LineChart from another ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, charts, segue, viewcontroller

I have 2 ViewControllers. ViewController A gets information and ViewController B sets the information in a line graph using the Charts framework.

I made it so that at the end of the day, the line graph gets updated. This works properly, however, the user has to open ViewController B in order for the Line Graph to update with the new information it received the day before.

How can I make it so that whenever the app opens. The graph is updated automatically without the need of opening ViewController B. I tried calling the function to make the chart from ViewController B in ViewController A but I get an error saying that the chart.info is nil.

I tried searching for a way to do it. But I couldn't find anything.

Here is ViewController B. And it is opened by a segue in ViewController A:

```
func makeChart(){
    let today = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
    let compare = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "userDate")

    print(today)


    print(ViewController.totalReps)
    // var points = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "array") as! [Int]
    var points: [Int] = []


  //Checks if the day passed
    if today != compare{
        UserDefaults.standard.set(today, forKey: "userDate")

    points = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "array") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()

        let userReps = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "userReps")
        points.append(userReps)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(points, forKey: "array")



    //UserDefaults.standard.set(points, forKey: "array")
    var chartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()

    print(points)
    for i in 0..<points.count {

        let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(points[i]))
        chartEntry.append(value)
    }

    let line = LineChartDataSet(values: chartEntry, label: "Reps")

    line.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
    let info = LineChartData()


    info.addDataSet(line)

    Chart.data = info

    Chart.chartDescription?.text = "Reps"

    //reset values
    ViewController.totalReps = 0
    UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "userReps")



    }
```

Comment: if you want to show chart in viewController B than you can update every time in viewWillApper.

Comment: Only you need to save data to userDefaults.

Comment: Hello, Is viewWillAppear in Viewcontroller A or B ?

Comment: Hello @AlexMerlin Every-time do save you changes in UserDefaults, And when you open the app In ViewController B automatically set the value of graph from User default so it will get reflected automatically without going to ViewController B. Or Second Solution if your chart data is Static i.e. if once added you dont need to delete it regularly then you can use Core Data.

Comment: Hello @AbhirajsinhThakore, the chart gets updated once the day is over. The app opens in ViewController A. So you are saying i should open the app showing the chart instead ?

Comment: No man I was saying that, That store the data of the Chart in an Array and then store the array into UserDefault. Show the data in Chart using this USerDefault, So when at end of the Day if data is updated in VC A it will be automatically reflected to ViewController B. If u want i can write a code for you to save Array into the UserDefault and then Utilise it

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a View controller B to Create a Chart 
I assume you are saving values Globally and that can be accessed in ViewController B

Just create a Empty Swift file and create a class as Described

```
class newLineChart: NSObject
{

    /// A Shared Instance
    /// This will Initiate class
    /// Using this we will directly use this class Created Components
    static var shared = LineChart()


    /// This is Main function through which chart is being created
    /// Just return chart created at the endf of function
    /// I used Swift Charts and i just used global Values of charts
    /// Accessed in Required func where chart is getting created
    /// At the end return chart
    /// Add the returned chart in my subviews
    func makeChanges() -> Chart
    {
        /// Your code goes Here
        /// Chart Instance
        /// Upadte Axis and all Labels as per requirement
        return Chart
    }
}
```

**Now in View Controller A**

```
/// Add Returned chart Subview
self.myCustomContainerView.addSubview(newLineChart.shared.makeChanges.view)
```

I Had used **SwiftCharts Framework**
my class Looks Like This

```
class DoubleSidedChart: NSObject
{
    /// Shared Instance
    static var shared = DoubleSidedChart()

    override init() {  }

    deinit {
        //Used
    }

}

//MARK:- Get into CSV File
extension DoubleSidedChart
{

    func createCharts(leftView:UIView,rightView:UIView) -> (Chart,Chart)
    {
        return (leftChart(realChartPoints: chartPointsForLeftChart, secondModel: secondLineCPLeft, leftChartView: leftView),rightChart(realChartPoints: chartPointsForRightChart, secondModel: secondLineCPRight, rightChartView: rightView))
    }
}

//MARK:- Get charts - DoubleSidedChart
extension DoubleSidedChart
{
    func leftChart(realChartPoints: [(Double,Double)],secondModel : [(Double,Double)], leftChartView: UIView) -> Chart
    {
        self.leftAxischart?.clearView()
        leftAxischart = nil

        /// My code for Left axis Chart

        //SubLayers
        self.leftAxischart = Chart(
            frame: chartFrame,
            innerFrame: innerFrame,
            settings: chartSettings,
            layers: [
                xAxisLayer,
                yAxisLayer,
                guidelinesLayer,
                chartPointsLineLayer,
                chartPointsLineLayer1
            ]
        )
        return leftAxischart!
    }
    func rightChart(realChartPoints: [(Double,Double)],secondModel : [(Double,Double)], rightChartView: UIView) -> Chart
    {
        self.rightAxisChart?.clearView()
        rightAxisChart = nil
        /// My code

        rightAxisChart = Chart(
            frame: chartFrame,
            innerFrame: innerFrame,
            settings: chartSettings,
            layers: [
                xAxisLayer,
                yAxisLayer,
                guidelinesLayer,
                chartPointsLineLayer,
                chartPointsLineLayer1
            ]
        )

        rightAxisChart?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return rightAxisChart!
    }
}
```

**My class Usage**

```
 var DSC : DoubleSidedChart?
 DSC = DoubleSidedChart()  

/// Add Subview
let DSCV = DSC?.createCharts(leftView: leftChartView, rightView: rightChartView)
leftChartView.addSubview((DSCV?.0.view)!)
rightChartView.addSubview((DSCV?.1.view)!)
```